# Use variable for property name of object

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I use a variable for the property name of an object?

```
 var foo = 'abc';
 var value = '123';
 var name = 'bar';

 $.ajax({
      url: foo.php,
      data: { code : foo , name : value }, // passed name (should be bar)
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data){}
 });
```

How could I do?
Thank You

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create `data` as a separate variable

```
var data = {code: foo};
data[name] = value;

 $.ajax({
      url: foo.php,
      data: data, 
      type: 'POST',
      success: function(data){}
 });
```